# How do I create a fake OpenID Connect Provider for testing an OAuth-2.0 (Java) server?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I need to develop a java Spring-Boot server that uses OAuth 2.0 to handle logins. Unfortunately, the very tight security on my office network prevents me from accessing well known OAuth 2.0 OpenId Connect providers like GitHub, so I need a fake OpenID Connect server to test my code. Everywhere I go for examples, I find advice that tells me to just use GitHub or some other site that's restricted. I'm not even clear on the protocol that a connection would use. How can I create a dummy OAuth 2.0 server (preferably in Java) to handle the identity layer of the protocol and feed me the necessary authorization grants?

Comment: There is a very good article by Tanzu. [Faking OAuth2](https://tanzu.vmware.com/content/pivotal-engineering-journal/faking-oauth2-single-sign-on-in-spring-3-ways). I personally would go with WireMock

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way to go for unit and integration testing of Spring resource-servers (REST APIs secured with OAuth2) is to use no authorization-server at all and mock Authentication. Have a look at unit and integration tests in this [tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) or [samples](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples) for illustration.

The exact way to do it depends on quite a few factors, but most are covered in samples linked above:

- are you using MockMvc or WebTestClient?
- Is your secured component under test a controller, a service, a repository?
- What type of Authentication have you configured? (what is the output of `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getClass()`? )

Now, for working with real client (like Angular app) connected to real resource-server (Spring API), I use a real authorization-server: either one from staging environments or a Keycloak instance running on my own machine (standalone or in a docker container).